# Redirect to login get 404 if debug is true Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, http-status-code-404

So this is my `web.php`

```
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
   Route::get('/add/{prod}', 'LandingPageController@addprod')->name('prod.add');
}
```

As you can see that route is under the `auth` middleware, but if I try to go for example to `/add/5` without logging in, I get `301` to login if `app.debug` is `true`, `404` if it's false

If I dump the error I get `Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException: Unauthenticated.`

### Edit

Looks like it caused by `Handler`, because I've edited a method:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if(config('app.debug')) return parent::render($request, $exception);
    else return response()->view('error',array(),404);
}
```

How can I use a my view for error and not getting this error?

Comment: You can define your custom 404 blade file in resources/views/errors.

Comment: @mohammad.kaab yes but by default they try to find "view/errors/{error_code}"... why should i define a error page for each one? i want just one view displayed for 5xx and 4xx

Comment: You need to define an if condition to catch the errors which starts with 4xx or 5xx, then base on the error code you could just show specific error page.

Comment: When writing questions here, please try to use "I" (upper case) for the personal pronoun. We do have some volunteer editors here who will make posts more readable for future readers, but it's better if we can get question authors to do it, especially if they are long-standing users who will write many more posts. Thank you!

Comment: @halfer sure, sorry, for foreigners is not that automatic to put it upper case ahah

Comment: No worries. I think an English spell-checker would catch that for you. `:-)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cleaner way to achieve this effect is by modifying [Laravel's exception handler](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/errors#the-exception-handler).

Modify `App\Exceptions\Handler` to catch every error and return your shared custom error page.

```
/**
 * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Exception  $e
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
        return response()->view('errors.custom', [], 404);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Some customization may be required to fully meet exactly what & how you want data passed to your shared custom view.

Comment: looking inside the trait, there is a renderHttpException or something like this, are there any difference?

Comment: What is Trait talking about? There's no Trait in the Handler